# 2 ScrollViews in xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms, scrollview

[Layout design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tgv2.jpg)

I need to use two ScrollViews in the same page. This is an image showing how I want to design my application.

I was thinking about using a grid layout of 3 rows, but i don't know how I can implement 2 scrollViews inside the second row in A and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are one the right way. you can use a grid-layout with 3 rows and 2 columns.

```
<GridLayout>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Frame x:Name="TOP"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
         ...
    </Frame>
    <ScrollView x:Name="LeftView"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Orienation="Vertical">
         ...
    </ScrollView>
    <ScrollView x:Name="RightView"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Orienation="Vertical">
         ...
    </ScrollView>            
    <Frame x:Name="BOTTOM"
           Grid.Row="2"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
         ...
    </Frame>           
</GridLayout>
```